# Can I upload my self hosted WordPress website on GitHub as a project?

Tags: customization, github

I have searched this question a lot

Can we call our WordPress Website a project?

and

Can we somehow upload our Wordpress Website as a Project on Github?

I have an e-Commerce based website, which is created on WordPress. And
I am new here so if the question is irrelevant, please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot host wordpress websites on Github.  But you can host static websites on Github Pages, if that's any help.  Try making a site with [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), and hosting it on Github. Its easy, fun and free.

My wordpress repos are all either themes or plugins.  I never add the wordpress core to a repo.  The project is always the theme or plugin folder.